# how create a drop down menu within a canvas in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

I'm working with the **Fabric js** and I am new to it can anybody tell me how to ***create a drop-down menu*** within a canvas in fabric js.

Comment: You are good dev. But this cannot happen (Impossible) beacause you are saying (How to draw dropdown in Fabric.JS). and we cannot draw a dropdown as well.

Comment: If you want to create dropdown create dropdown in regular DOM which it will be more much easier as well.

Comment: Thanks
Actually, I want to add a drop-down menu on canvas 
When the user click on drop-down text then list appears

Comment: Use `fabric.Text` then on click make list appear as I think.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a guide on writing a good question. It's important to explain what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried so far, what alternatives you've considered, and share a working example of the code that is causing you trouble.